# Binding or populating multiple Windows Form Combo Boxes to MS Access Database

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, combobox

I have a winform application that connects to a MS Access database. On my client based page which in my case is for Wendy's restaurants i have selections for the state that the restaurant is in, what the wall or roof structure is, etc. When the end user is on this page i want to be able to select from these various combo boxes to select the options that are in my MS database file in order to add a new record or update an existing record. I have looked at some other post on stackoverflow where the author had created a method for for one combo box & called it from a form_load section of their program but i am trying to populate multiple combo boxes to my database. I've seen other things around the web where someone bound the combo box to a dataset. Right now i have the one combo box defined in the WendysForm_Load section of my program. Is it better to create a method for every combo box & call it from my Form_load section or is it better to bind all of the combo boxes to my dataset? Here is my code & i have also attached an image:

```
private void WendysForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)//Start of WendysForm_Load code
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'cDG_Project_TypesDataSet.Wendys' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.wendysTableAdapter.Fill(this.cDG_Project_TypesDataSet.Wendys);
            try
            {


            connection.Open();//Open Connection
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();//Create command object of OleDbCommand
            command.Connection = connection;//This tells OleDbCommand command object to use OleDbConnection connection variable to connect to Access Database
            string query = "SELECT DISTINCT State FROM Wendys";//SQL Statement for Combo Boxes(Still need to figure out how to do multiple Combo Boxes!!!!!!)
            //string query = "SELECT DISTINCT [" + sqlColumnName.ToString() + "] FROM [database].[dbo].[Wendys];";
            //"SELECT DISTINCT AssetType FROM Wendys";
            //"SELECT DISTINCT BaseModel FROM Wendys";
            //"SELECT DISTINCT BldgPrototypeYear FROM Wendys";
            //"SELECT DISTINCT UpgradeClass FROM Wendys";
            //"SELECT DISTINCT ExtWallStructure FROM Wendys";
            //"SELECT DISTINCT NewWallStructure FROM Wendys";
            //"SELECT DISTINCT ExtRoofStructure FROM Wendys";
            //"SELECT DISTINCT NewRoofStructure FROM Wendys";
            //"SELECT DISTINCT ExstFoundationType FROM Wendys";
            //"SELECT DISTINCT NewFoundationType FROM Wendys";
            //"SELECT DISTINCT Addition FROM Wendys";
            //"SELECT DISTINCT BladeDesign FROM Wendys";
            //"SELECT DISTINCT DriveThruType FROM Wendys";
            //"SELECT DISTINCT Patio FROM Wendys";
            //"SELECT DISTINCT TrashEnclosure FROM Wendys";
            //"SELECT DISTINCT CounterStyle FROM Wendys";
            //"SELECT DISTINCT SelfServe FROM Wendys";
            //"SELECT DISTINCT DigitalStatic FROM Wendys";
            //"SELECT DISTINCT RaisedCeiling,Notes FROM Wendys";
            //"SELECT DISTINCT Notes FROM Wendys";


            command.CommandText = query;//This asigns string variable query to command.CommandText object

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();//This executes Query
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                //Populate Combo Boxes with Access Database fields(Still need to figure out how to do multiple Combo Boxes!!!!!!)
                cb_State.Items.Add(reader["State"].ToString());
                //    cb_AssetType.Items.Add(reader["AssetType"].ToString());
                //    cb_BaseModel.Items.Add(reader["BaseModel"].ToString());
                //    cb_BldgPrototypeYear.Items.Add(reader["BldgPrototypeYear"].ToString());
                //    cb_UpgradeClass.Items.Add(reader["UpgradeClass"].ToString());
                //    cb_ExtWallStructure.Items.Add(reader["ExtWallStructure"].ToString());
                //    cb_NewWallStructure.Items.Add(reader["NewWallStructure"].ToString());
                //    cb_ExtRoofStructure.Items.Add(reader["ExtRoofStructure"].ToString());
                //    cb_NewRoofStructure.Items.Add(reader["NewRoofStructure"].ToString());
                //    cb_ExtFndType.Items.Add(reader["ExstFoundationType"].ToString());
                //    cb_NewFndType.Items.Add(reader["NewFoundationType"].ToString());
                //    cb_Addition.Items.Add(reader["Addition"].ToString());
                //    cb_BladeDesign.Items.Add(reader["BladeDesign"].ToString());
                //    cb_DriveThruType.Items.Add(reader["DriveThruType"].ToString());
                //    cb_Patio.Items.Add(reader["Patio"].ToString());
                //    cb_TrashEnclosure.Items.Add(reader["TrashEnclosure"].ToString());
                //    cb_CounterStyle.Items.Add(reader["CounterStyle"].ToString());
                //    cb_SelfServe.Items.Add(reader["SelfServe"].ToString());
                //    cb_MenuboardType.Items.Add(reader["DigitalStatic"].ToString());
                //    cb_RaisedCeiling.Items.Add(reader["RaisedCeiling"].ToString());
                //    list_Notes.Items.Add(reader["Notes"].ToString());




            }

            connection.Close();//Close Connection
        }//End of try for WendysForm_Load
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error  " + ex);
        }//end of catch for WendysForm_Load
    }//End of code for WendysForm_Load
```

[My winform called WendysForm is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3tlT.jpg)

[My Combo Box Task Dialog box is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYZ8I.jpg)

Comment: Doesn't matter, anyway you will need to define own `DataSource` for every `ConboBox`. But having own method for every `ComboBox` seems better for maintaining and future changes

Comment: ok, thanks for replying

Comment: Use a `DataSet` designer containing `DataTable` and `TableAdapter` for all your tables which you want to use as `DataSource` of your `ComboBox` controls. This way you can have designer support and more clean code. Then a single instance of `DataSet` will be enough and you will fill `DataTable`s of the `DataSet` using `TableAdapters` and perform data-binding using designer.

Comment: Would you please elaborate on what you mean by dataset designer? I created a dataset with the wizard. I tried to connect my combobox to it by clicking on the properties of my combobox & changing the data source to my data set either nothing gets populated or i getSystem.Data.DataViewManagerListItemTypeDescriptor . I'm obviously doing something wrong. I get a message saying i'm currently bound to CDGProjectTypesDataSetBindingSource

Comment: Interesting. I have watched a couple of youtube videos on this. I like how the grid, combo boxes & text boxes are connected with the binding navigator. If only now i can find out how to populate the combo box with the couple of options that are in my MS Access fields & then have that show up in the grid i would be very happy. For instance, if i am adding a new record or updating an existing record i would love to be able to select the correct "State" & have it show up in the grid. Although it looks like i wasted alot of time doing it with traditional combo boxes, text boxes,etc.

Comment: Well, i am still experimenting with this. I wish i knew what the right thing to do was. I need to look at some more info on data sources. I either get the combo box populated with every instance of the field info or i get the combo box populated with "System.Data.DataRowView". I added a screenshot of the combo box task for clarity